# Do later levels increase odds of better chests?

Tags: stone-story-rpg

Playing a level on a higher star difficulty will improve the odds of the end chest being better (i.e. delta, omega, etc), but is this also true for later levels?  For example, would playing the Temple on 5 stars tend to give better chests than Deadwood Canyon?

Answer (score 1):

Deadwood Canyon at white or cyan is different than other locations, but comparing Temple to Caves of Fear, the loot probability is the same. That said, treasure balance is on the roadmap and will change meaningfully in a future update.